# DIY battery from scratch. Is it possible?

Tags: batteries, diy

Batteries are expensive. I want to be able to store about 30 kW worth, but even the cheapest kinds of batteries, like Lead-acid, or Salt Water batteries are too much. I've looked into reviving dead ones, but that seems like a hopeless and fruitless endeavor. 
What about making my own? Well, that's where hopefully you folks can give me some insight. Is there any home remedies that you could think of, anything that I may have missed in the internet?

Comment: Google Baghdad battery...... Although you may need a few of them!

Comment: If it was possible, some company would make them in bulk, cheaper. (And how long do you need 30kW to last? or did you mean 30kWh?)

Comment: 30 kW is a power measurement. Batteries store energy, not power. Energy is power x time and, as mentioned above, the units are usually in kWh.

Comment: I believe there is some work on DIY NiFe batteries, e.g. https://www.fieldlines.com/index.php?topic=148628.0 ; 30kWh is a large battery however you slice it.

Comment: Your not going to make a battery cheaper than a manufacturer could. They have economies of scale on their side, you don't.

Comment: Cars are expensive too. Why don't we make our own cheaper cars in our garages?

Comment: If it was possible, someone would of done it, commercialized it and retired with Scrooge McDuck kind on money.  But the world relies on the dreamers, not reality.

Answer (score 14):

Any battery you buy is going to be far cheaper than one you build. Those folks who make them for a living have a lot of know-how, experience, machinery to make them, techniques to get large surface area from small amounts of expensive raw materials etc etc, stuff you don't have.

How about cast a large weight from concrete and hang it from an electrical machine on a tall tower? Although, when I do the sums, a 17 tonne weight with 10m drop is the energy stored in a 40Ah car battery. Perhaps just buy the batteries.

Comment: I have never done that calculation before. I now have a renewed respect for lead acid batteries  (and large suspended weights)  :).

Comment: How about a flywheel accumulator?

Comment: @AliChen I remember as a student (I'm now retired) reading in Scientific American about flywheel design for energy storage. Paradoxically, GRP and carbon fibre are the best materials, high strength/weight ratio. I understand there are/were a few public service vehicles on the road that charge their flywheels at stops. A problem with mobile  is the immense forces due to gyroscoping. A problem with all applications is bearing failure, and containment of all that energy being released the quick way. If you get a decent specific energy, you have a decent bomb. If not, then it's not worth doing.

Comment: Neil, I didn't mean mobile application, the example of 17 tonne on 10m doesn't look like mobile. What I hoped from you is to get a quick sense of what a flywheel machine would be for the same task. http://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/7/3/286/pdf